# Two commands, one pipeline

Tags: bash, dns

I need these two commands to be ***one*** (so I can pipe them further):

```
dig +nottlid -t any bix.hu | egrep -v "^;;|^;|^$" | sort
dig +nottlid -t any www.bix.hu | egrep -v "^;;|^;|^$" | sort
```

I mean I need the output of these two commands to be in one pipe:

```
$ dig +nottlid -t any bix.hu | egrep -v "^;;|^;|^$" | sort
bix.hu.         IN  A   193.239.149.1
bix.hu.         IN  MX  10 deneb.iszt.hu.
bix.hu.         IN  NS  ns.iszt.hu.
bix.hu.         IN  NS  ns.iszt.hu.
bix.hu.         IN  NS  ns-s.nic.hu.
bix.hu.         IN  NS  ns-s.nic.hu.
bix.hu.         IN  SOA ns.iszt.hu. hostmaster.iszt.hu. 2011053000 28800 7200 604800 14400
```

and

```
dig +nottlid -t any www.bix.hu | egrep -v "^;;|^;|^$" | sort
bix.hu.         IN  NS  ns.iszt.hu.
bix.hu.         IN  NS  ns-s.nic.hu.
www.bix.hu.     IN  A   193.239.149.1
```

so that I could `sha256sum` them together, without writing the output of the two commands to one file, and `sha256sum` the file.

Q: it's like this:

```
echo hi | echo hi2 | sha256sum
```

of course this won't work, but are there any solutions for this? So that I need the sha256sum of:

```
hi
hi2
-->>
697ec886148d94d5b094df14f301f2e5a4abd8098a0e0dc2afb0a97945cea677
```

but I can only have the outputs from different commands [mentioned above, 2 different domains]. [Just want to write a "DNS checker" script to warn me when DNS records changes for a domain]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can pass multiple names to `dig`:

```
dig +nottlid -t any bix.hu www.bix.hu | egrep -v "^;;|^;|^$" | sort
```

Answer (score 33):

A general solution is the following:

```
{ command1; command2; } | some-other-command
```

Comment: Or `( command1; command2; ) | some-other-command`.

Comment: @hlovdal: yes, but in such a case you are running a subshell (someone would prefer to know), and the second `;` is not required.

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways to get exactly that output without grepping:

Turn off the sections you don't want:

```
dig +nottlid +nocomments +noquestion +nostats +nocmd -t any bix.hu
```

Turn off all the sections then turn on the sections you do want:

```
dig +nottlid +noall +authority +answer +additional -t any bix.hu
```

Also, it seems the output gives a different `additional` (or "`glue`") section each time, so you might want to use `+noadditional` if you're just trying to check for changes to the zone file.