# Pipe output of two programs running in parallel to another program

Tags: pipe, io-redirection, background-process

I have two programs `foo.sh` and `bar.sh` both of which contain infite loops, produce continuous Output and should run in parallel. I would like to pipe the output of both those programs to a third program `consumer`.

Initially I only had `foo.sh` running and the piping was easy via

```
./foo.sh | ./consumer
```

But now I would like to add `bar.sh` to also send its output to `consumer`.

I have tried the things suggested in those answers ([Answer 1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64736/combine-output-from-two-commands-in-bash), [Answer 2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23627/two-commands-one-pipeline?rq=1)) but they only seem to work for programs where one ends and the next gets started after the first one ends. I need them both to run in parallel.

This does not work, as it only pipes the output of `foo.sh` and never starts `bar.sh`:

```
( ./foo.sh ; ./bar.sh ) | ./consumer
```

This lucky guess gave me a syntax error:

```
( ./foo.sh & ; ./bar.sh & ) | ./consumer
```

Comment: Did answer 1's `{ command1 & command2; } | ...` not work for you?

Comment: To me it seemed it was only piping the output of command1 but never starting command2, as command1 will run indefinitely.

Comment: How did it seem that way? It *doesn't* do that, but that's not to say there wasn't some other issue that's your real problem.

Comment: ok sorry for the wording. It only pipes the Output of command1, command2 is never started. If I reverse them, I get it the other way around.

Comment: Yeah, exactly, that's not how it works, so you do have a different problem. `command1` runs in the background and `command2` starts shortly after. Try `{ yes y & yes n  ; } | cat` and see. You may need to provide your actual commands for someone to help you.

Comment: I am sorry. The original answers were working. It was an issue of not flushing the stdout buffer. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the semicolon from your lucky guess...